# Simplify $\frac{[m+n-1]!}{[m]![n]!}$ where $[k]=x^k-x^{-k}$ and $[k]!=[2][3]...[k]$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factorial

Adopting the notation $[k] = x^k - x^{-k} $ and $[k]! = [2][3]...[k]$ (note that $[1]$ is omitted), and letting $m,n$ be two integers greater than $1$ such that $n>m$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$, would it be possible to write
$$ \frac{1}{[m+n]}\binom{m+n}{m}_q = \frac{[m+n-1]!}{[m]![n]!} = \frac{[n+1][n+2]...[n+m-1]}{[m]!} = \frac{[n+1][n+2]...[n+m-1]}{[2][3]...[m]}  $$
in the form:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k c_i (x^i+x^{-i})  $$

I know that if $l=mn$, then $\frac{[l]}{[n]} = x^{(l-1)n} + x^{(l-3)n} + ... + x^{-(l-1)n}$, but other than that I'm pretty much stuck.

Answers for some small $m,n$ are:
$$(2,3): x^2 + x^{-2}$$
$$(2,5): x^4 + 1 + x^{-4}$$
$$(3,4): x^6 + x^2 + 1 + x^{-2} + x^{-6}$$
$$(3,5): x^8 + x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^{-2} + x^{-4} + x^{-8}$$
$$(4,5): x^{12} + x^8 + x^6 + 2x^4 + x^2 + 2 + x^{-2} + 2x^{-4} + x^{-6} + x^{-8} + x^{-12}$$

Edit: The fraction should be some product of cyclotomic polynomials I think, because:
$$x^k-x^{-k} = x^{-k}(x^{2k}-1)=x^{-k}\Pi_{d|2k} \Phi_d(x)$$

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. If you were just looking for $$\frac{(n+m-1)!}{n!m!}=\frac{1}{n+m}\binom{n+m}{n}$$ this would be a very different problem.

Comment: This looks like it will end up being related to the $q-$binomial coefficients, also called the Gaussian binomial  coefficients, where $q=x^{-2}$. But I haven't worked out the details. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $[k]=x^k-x^{-k}=x^{-k}(x^{2k}-1)=x^{-k}\Pi_{d|2k} \Phi_d (x)$ with $\Phi_d(x)$ the d-th cyclotomic polynomial. So both the enumerator and denominator can be written as product of cyclotomic polynomials. After cancelling common terms the result should be a product of cyclotomic polynomials multiplied by $x^k$ for some $k$.